# Cakephp Auth Login not working with a different user table

Tags: php, cakephp, authentication, authorization, cakephp-2.x

having problems with this function. Unfortunately when the user goes to login, the login page is showing error: "Invalid username or password, try again" instead of signing them in and redirecting them to the index page.

My User_Details table has the following fields: User_Details(user_id, user_name, user_password, email, created, modified).

This is my code for the login function which is in BlogDetailsController:

```
public function login() {
    $this->loadModel('UserDetail');
    $this->layout = 'login';

    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        //print_r($this->request->data);
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {
            return $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirectUrl());
        }
        $this->Flash->error(__('Invalid username or password, try again'));
    }
}
```

This is my code for the AppController:

```
    App::uses('Controller', 'Controller');

class AppController extends Controller {

    // added the debug toolkit
    // sessions support
    // authorization for login and logut redirect
    public $components = array(
        'DebugKit.Toolbar',
        'Flash',
        'Session', //Session
        'Auth' => array(//Auth
            'loginAction' => array('controller' => 'BlogDetails', 'action' => 'login'),
            'loginRedirect' => array('controller' => 'BlogDetails', 'action' => 'index'),
            'logoutRedirect' => array('controller' => 'BlogDetails', 'action' => 'login'),
            'authError' => "Sorry, you're not allowed to access this page.",
            'Form' => array(
                'userModel' => 'UserDetail',
                'fields' => array('username' => 'user_name', 'password' => 'user_password'))
        )
    );

    // only allow the login controllers only
    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Auth->allow('login');
    }

}
```

This is my code for login.ctp :

```
<?php
echo $this->Flash->render('auth');
echo $this->Form->create('UserDetail', array(
    'inputDefaults' => array(
        'div' => array('class' => 'form-group'),
        'class' => 'form-control',
        'label' => false
    )
));
echo $this->Form->input('user_name', array(
    'before' => '<span class="input-with-icon"><i class="fa fa-user"></i>',
    'after' => '</span>',
    'type' => 'text',
    'title' => 'Please enter username',
    'placeholder' => "User Name",
    'data-rule-requiredchardigitsonly' => true));
echo $this->Form->input('user_password', array(
    'before' => '<span class="input-with-icon"><i class="fa fa-key"></i>',
    'after' => '</span>',
    'type' => 'password',
    'title' => 'Please enter password',
    'placeholder' => "Your Password",
    'data-rule-digit' => true));
$options = array(
    'label' => 'Sign in',
    'div' => array(
        'class' => 'form-group',
    ),
    'class' => 'form-control btn btn-primary',
);
echo $this->Form->end($options);
?>
```

Hopefully someone could point out what's going wrong..

I am using cakephp version 2.8.1

Comment: `public function beforeFilter() {$this->Auth->allow('login');$this->Auth->authenticate = array(
    'Basic' => array('userModel' => 'UserDetail'),
    'Form' => array('userModel' => 'UserDetail')
);`  do this and check

Comment: tried this but still facing same problem. "Invalid username or password, try again"

Comment: sql_dump giving following results: SELECT `UserDetail`.`user_id`,  `UserDetail`.`user_name`, `UserDetail`.`user_password`, `UserDetail`.`email`, `UserDetail`.`created`, `UserDetail`.`modified` FROM `blog`.`user_details` AS `UserDetail` WHERE `UserDetail`.`user_name` = 'admin' LIMIT 1

Answer (score 0):

```
public function beforeSave($options = array()) {
        // hash our password
        if (isset($this->data[$this->alias]['user_password'])) {
            $this->data[$this->alias]['user_password'] = AuthComponent::password($this->data[$this->alias]['user_password']);
        }

        // fallback to our parent
        return parent::beforeSave($options);
    }
```

Added to UserDetail Model and it worked.